# Sent data to master nodes or all nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I call the `bulk` api to write data to the `es` cluster.Just sent data to the master nodes or send data to all nodes include data nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since master nodes don't hold any data, if you send your bulk queries to them, there will be two hops (client -> master + master -> data)  until the data arrives at a data node to be indexed.

For this reason, you need to send your bulk queries directly to one data node of your cluster and it will happily index the data.

Comment: `shard = hash(routing) % number_of_primary_shards`,es will calculate the document belong to which shard and which node.For example,the `document` belong to `shard 0` in `node1`,but i bulk data to 'node2', there will be two hops (client -> node2 + node2 -> node1)?

Comment: Of course, but there will always be one less hop than if you go to the master node first, which was your initial question.

Comment: But,`datanode` should index the data,and do search,transfer data  to another `node` if that affects the issue?

Comment: Not at all, don't worry. Try it out and you'll see it's not really a problem.